# having issues with css element placement

Tags: css

[image]

The grey element, a div with id of #banner is not meant to be sticking out, I gave all the elements inside the div containing the welcome to fusion box, red element, and banner a min-height which adds up to all the min-heights of the elements inside it (welcome to fusion cube, red element, banner).

Basically it's not meant to stick out and I just can't figure out why it is sticking out.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enx0hc6w/)

Not really something productive to ask but I can't figure it out and it's stressful

```
#main-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    height: calc(75.5% - 10px);
    margin: 10px auto 0;


    min-height: 250px;
}
    #page-title {
        height: 7%;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px 0 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        min-height: 35px;
    }
    #content-wrapper {
        background: red;
        height: 83%;

        min-height: 160px;
    }
        #page-messages {
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    #banner {
        height: 10%;
        display: inline-block;
        background: grey;

    min-height: 55px;
}
footer {
    height: 8%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.5%;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you defined `#banner` as an  `inline-block` - is that intention? (= not spanning the whole width?). Your fiddle looks quite different from the screenshot you posted...

try making its `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0px;`, and give the parent element (#main-wrapper) `position: relative`, and also a `margin-bottom` as high as `#banner`, which prevents content to be hidden by `#banner`.

(edited, wrong name for parent element)

Comment: yeah my bad on the difference between the screenshot and the fiddle, I did the fiddle after i put the screenshot in the post and I realised it looked weird so i changed it, in the screenshot i left it like that to show the problem clearly

Comment: what I find weird is that all the heights I set add up but when i open the page it's different

Comment: oh, the issue isn't that, the issue is that banner is overflowing outside of #main-wrapper, when it's not meant to

Comment: well, that's why I would attach it's bottom border to the bottom of #main-wrapper as described in my answer

Comment: it's a fix i guess however it leaves a 55px gap between #content-wrapper and #banner but i guess it's better than before

Comment: oh yeah, however i tried that and i saw it engulfs the messages div so i did this https://jsfiddle.net/gkcyks4v/  this way i can still see the messages div, that div will be used for form validation and login msg.